# Failed to send email in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, devise

I get this error

```
getaddrinfo: Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

in heroku when sending confirmation email after user signup.

I am using elastic email as smtp and I cant find any addons for that in heroku. Do I need an addon just to send an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the err was due to parsing of smtp_port as string. Typecasting smtp_port to integer will fix the issue. Surprisingly, I could only replicate the error in heroku.

```
  # smtp mail setup
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'abc.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              ENV['SMTP_ADDRESS'],
    port:                 ENV['SMTP_PORT'].to_i,
    domain:               ENV['SMTP_DOMAIN'],
    user_name:            ENV['SMTP_USER_NAME'],
    password:             ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.default_options = { from: 'contact@abc.com' }
```